# Is it safe to store a reference to an element of a list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

Is it safe to store a reference to an element in a `std::list` as long as that element is not removed from the list? I see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837267/safe-to-store-listiterator-for-later-use) question that it is safe to store list iterators, but is the same true for direct references?

For example

```
list<int> mylist;
mylist.push_back(3);
int& myint = *mylist.begin();

// modfy mylist

cout << "myint: " << myint << endl;
```

will `myint` always be valid as long I don't remove it from the list?

Comment: Does it compile? I believe it should be `int& myint = *mylist.begin()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it safe to store a reference to an element in a `std::list` as long as that element is not removed from the list?

Yes.  Insertions and erasures do not invalidate references or iterators to elements in a `std::list` (except, of course, that references and iterators to an erased element is no longer valid).

Comment: Please add a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's safe.  The element won't move, so the reference will only be invalidated in the same circumstances that the iterator would.